# Async IndexRoute doesn't load with react-router

Tags: javascript, react-router

I can't get my index route (Home component) to load, would really appreciate some help as to what I'm doing wrong?

My routes.js file looks like this

```
module.exports = <Route 
    path="/" 
    getComponent={(location, cb) => {
      require.ensure([], (require) => {
        cb(null, require('./Container'))
      })
    }}
    getChildRoutes={(location, cb) => {
      require.ensure([], (require) => {
        cb(null, require('./Container').childRoutes)
      })
    }}
    getIndexRoute={(location, cb) => {
      require.ensure([], (require) => {
        cb(null, require('./Container').indexRoute)
      })
    }}
/>
```

and my Container.js file looks like this

```
export default class Container extends Component {
  render = () => {
    return <div>
      {this.props.children}
    </div>
  }
}

Container.childRoutes = [
  <Route 
    path="/:product/get-quote"
    component={props => <Product productName={props.params.product} {...props} />}
  />,
  <Route 
    path="/:product/processing-quote"
    component={props => <ProcessingQuote productName={props.params.product} {...props} />}
  />
]

Container.indexRoute = <IndexRoute component={Home} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the `getChildRoutes` and `getIndexRoute` handlers, you should use [`PlainRoute`](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v2.0.0-rc6/docs/API.md#plainroute) configuration objects, rather than the JSX components.

Comment: Changing to `Container.indexRoute = { component: Home }` worked thanks taion